# Why some of my Data Annotations in my dto class are not working when I validate the Model in my WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, data-annotations

I have Dto class with data annotations on my properties, but one of them is getting ignored when ModelValidation is performed:

Dto Class:

```
public class TestClassDto {
 [Required()] //This one is getting ignored!
 public virtual System.Guid Id { get; set; }

 [StringLength(32)]
 [Required()]
 public virtual string Type { get; set; }

 [Required()]
 public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Original Class:

```
public class TestClass {
 public virtual System.Guid Id { get; set; }

 public virtual string Type { get; set; }

 public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

My Post Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostTestClass([FromBody] TestClassDto testClassDto) {
  //if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState); Explicit ModelState Validation is not necessary because ControllerBase makes Validation automatically

  TestClass testClass = _mapper.Map<TestClassDto, TestClass>(testClassDto);
  _uow.TestClassRepository.Add(testClass);

  try {
    await _uow.CompleteAsync();
  } catch (DbUpdateException ex) {
    return StatusCode(500, ex.ToString());
  }

  TestClassDto result = _mapper.Map<TestClass, TestClassDto>(testClass);

  return CreatedAtAction("GetTestClass", new { id = result.Id }, "Great");
}
```

Why is this happening? Any ideas would be helpful! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Give a try to make it nullable i.e `Guid?`

Answer (score 4):

`System.Guid` is a value type and it has a default value (actually an instance of) `Guid.Empty`, so it's never null. Because of that, the `[Required]` attribute will always pass the validation.

One of the solutions and probably the easiest one is to make the Guid nullable, like so:

`[Required]
 public virtual System.Guid? Id { get; set; }`

or the longer version:

`[Required]
 public virtual Nullable<System.Guid> Id { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

The RequiredAttribute check value is null for validation, the source of attribute:

```
override bool IsValid(object value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return false;
    }

    // only check string length if empty strings are not allowed
    var stringValue = value as string;
    if (stringValue != null && !AllowEmptyStrings) {
        return stringValue.Trim().Length != 0;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Because System.Guid is ValueType, its value is never null. make Id nullable solve your problem:

```
public virtual System.Guid? Id { get; set; }
```